# Calculate mean and standard deviation in Wireshark

Tags: microsoft-excel, wireshark

I have a situation where I have to calculate standard deviation and mean of how bytes per second varies over time. I have read how to calculate both standard deviation and mean but I have captured more then 50k packets using wireshark and I REALLY don't wanna do this manually... :S Is there any way to do this in Wireshark? I found I was able to show a graph of the bytes/s of the packets but so far no way to do the math? Help appreciated!

Update 1.
I have a excel document formatted like this...

```
Time    Source  Destination Protocol    Length  Info
0.000000    10.14.14.40 239.1.2.3   MPEG TS 1358    1234  >  1234 Len=1316 [MP2T fragment of a reassembled packet]
0.000575    10.14.14.40 239.1.2.3   MPEG TS 1358    1234  >  1234 Len=1316
0.000913    10.14.14.40 239.1.2.3   MPEG TS 1358    [MP2T fragment of a reassembled packet] [MP2T fragment of a reassembled packet] Program Association Table (PAT)  Program Map Table (PMT) 
0.001244    10.14.14.40 239.1.2.3   MPEG TS 1358    [MP2T fragment of a reassembled packet]
0.001576    10.14.14.40 239.1.2.3   MPEG TS 1358    [MP2T fragment of a reassembled packet]
0.001909    10.14.14.40 239.1.2.3   MPEG TS 1358    [MP2T fragment of a reassembled packet]
0.002241    10.14.14.40 239.1.2.3   MPEG TS 1358    [MP2T fragment of a reassembled packet]
0.002574    10.14.14.40 239.1.2.3   MPEG TS 1358    [MP2T fragment of a reassembled packet] [MP2T fragment of a reassembled packet]
0.002575    10.14.14.40 239.1.2.3   MPEG TS 1358    [MP2T fragment of a reassembled packet]
```

Update 2.
The average is for the entire capture period.

Comment: do you need a solution in Excel of wireshark? You may can do it in Excel using functions, please post same sample data with desired results.

Comment: preferable in wireshark but excel is okay too..

Comment: The missing piece of information here is the time window in "varies over time". You're going to calculate a moving average of the Bps and a moving s.d.  Is the average per minute, per hour, or what? Once you answer that question, average the first n rows where n is the number of rows in your time window. Same for sd. Fill those down to the end of your data and graph them.

Comment: it's the average for the entire capture

Comment: If that's true, then your graphs will be a flat line.  There will be only one value for the mean and one for the sd.  The formulas are =AVERAGE(Bps column) and STDEV(Bps column). If you want to shown the mean and sd on the same graph as the Bps, just have the mean and sd shown at both the beginning and end of the data.  Usually you show the sd as a range of +/- 2 sd around the mean.  I'll put an example in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about Wireshark, but I'll give you a solution in Excel, and that might help you do it in Wireshark.

The difficult part here is the mass of data you have.  I would *not* try to graph 50k data points, it would be overkill and almost unreadable.  Here's how I would approach the problem:

1. Select a representative subset of your data.  If you take every 50th data point, that will still be 1000 points on the graph.  If your times are in column A , then put

`=OFFSET(A$2,50*(row()-1),0)`

in a new column (say H2) and fill down 1000 rows.  Do the same for
    your bps column.

2. Calculate the mean and standard deviation of all 50k data points.  Also calculate the mean +/- 2 sd's.  The formulas for doing this are:

`=AVERAGE(F:F)` and `=STDEV(F:F)`

(Assuming your bps values are in column F).  Put these numbers in a new data table along with the first and last times from your selected data.  See the example below.

[image]

3. Now you can graph the Bps from your new, abbreviated data table, and
   add the mean and sd lines from the small table.  You should end up
   with something like this:

[image]

You only need two data points to draw the mean and sd lines since they are essentially constants.  The +/- 2 sd range is roughly the 95% confidence interval of your bps data, which is why this kind of plot is commonly used.

I hope I'm reading your question correctly.  Let me know if I've misunderstood or if you have other questions.

Answer (score 0):

To show what I ended up doing..
I created a java application to calculate standard deviation and mean programmatically. This way I could import a Wireshark .pcap file.

Here is the link to the github repository.
https://github.com/APayerl/PacketBitrateCalculator